# Apache, set a system path as an absolute path

Tags: php, apache

I am currently working on a PHP project, but I am looking for advice on how to allow PHP access to a system drive path; like f:\USBDrive

I want for the application to access media on this path.

Is there any possible way to map to accomplish this?

Comment: Please, tell us your operating system.

Comment: Windows 10

I am okay for Linux, as it is easier to add a virtual directory within the Apache config, but Windows, not so